# Entry field doesn't exist, it is made inside of a function

Tags: python, tkinter

so im trying to make a user login system, when a user clicks sign up and enters their password and username, it appends both of those to a file, however I made the entry field in the function that is called when you click sign in, Now i have an error when trying to get the data from that entry

```
   usr = (Usrfield).get()
NameError: name 'Usrfield' is not defined
```

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
Homescreen = Tk()

def addattrs():
    Signup = Tk()
    Usrfield = Entry(Signup, width=50)
    #Usrfield = signupinput.get(1.0, "end-1c") c
    Usrfield.insert(0, "What is ur usr")
    Usrfield.pack()
    Pswrdfield = Entry(Signup, width=50)
    Pswrdfield.insert(0, "Password?")
    Pswrdfield.pack()
    Homescreen.withdraw()
    loginbtn = Button(Signup, text="sign up", command=createusr)
    loginbtn.pack()

def login():
   Login= Toplevel(Homescreen)
   Login.geometry("750x250")
   Login.title("New Window")
   Label(Login, text="Youve logged in?", font=('Helvetica 17 bold')).pack(pady=30)
   Homescreen.withdraw()

def signup():
  #create window

  Homescreen.withdraw()
  addattrs()
def createusr():
    usr = (Usrfield).get()
    password = Pswrdfield.get()

    with open("Usernames.txt", "a+") as usrs:
        usrs.write(usr)
        usrs.write("\n")
    with open("Passwords.txt", "a+") as pswrds:
        pswrds.write(password)
        pswrds.write("\n")  


#Create a label
Label(Homescreen, text= "Click the below button to Open a New Window", font= ('Helvetica 17 bold')).pack(pady=30)
#Create a button to open a New Window
to_login = Button(Homescreen, text="Login", command=login).pack()
to_signup = Button(Homescreen, text="Sign up", command=signup).pack()


Homescreen.mainloop()
```

I tried defining the new screen after the original one closed but the program stopped running before the code could execute

Answer (score 0):

just make your widgets global in addattr() function. use the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
Homescreen = Tk()

def addattrs():
    global Usrfield,Pswrdfield
    Signup = Tk()
    Usrfield = Entry(Signup, width=50)
    #Usrfield = signupinput.get(1.0, "end-1c") c
    Usrfield.insert(0, "What is ur usr")
    Usrfield.pack()
    Pswrdfield = Entry(Signup, width=50)
    Pswrdfield.insert(0, "Password?")
    Pswrdfield.pack()
    Homescreen.withdraw()
    loginbtn = Button(Signup, text="sign up", command=createusr)
    loginbtn.pack()

def login():
   Login= Toplevel(Homescreen)
   Login.geometry("750x250")
   Login.title("New Window")
   Label(Login, text="Youve logged in?", font=('Helvetica 17 bold')).pack(pady=30)
   Homescreen.withdraw()

def signup():
  #create window

  Homescreen.withdraw()
  addattrs()
def createusr():
    usr = (Usrfield).get()
    password = Pswrdfield.get()

    with open("Usernames.txt", "a+") as usrs:
        usrs.write(usr)
        usrs.write("\n")
    with open("Passwords.txt", "a+") as pswrds:
        pswrds.write(password)
        pswrds.write("\n")  


#Create a label
Label(Homescreen, text= "Click the below button to Open a New Window", font= ('Helvetica 17 bold')).pack(pady=30)
#Create a button to open a New Window
to_login = Button(Homescreen, text="Login", command=login).pack()
to_signup = Button(Homescreen, text="Sign up", command=signup).pack()


Homescreen.mainloop()
```

have fun :)

Comment: thanks, Ive been working on this bug for like 3 days